# Calculus 1 - Optimization of a Unit Square

Tags: calculus

Problem: Let ABCD be a unit square. Find the coordinates of point P on line segment CD so that the perimeter of triangle ABP is:

a) minimal b) maximal.

I tried to take the derivative of the equation for the perimeter of a triangle [P= a + b + c], but am not sure as to how to find the coordinate points of P. Would I set the derived function equal to 0 and find the critical points?

I know the answer is supposed to be:

a) (1/2 , 1)

b) (0 , 1) and (1 , 0)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need calculus to solve this problem. Just reflect the square $ABCD$ about the line $CD$ to form the reflected square $A'B'CD$. Now you have to find $P$ on the line $CD$ to minimise (resp. maximise) $AP+PB'$. Once you have drawn the diagram, it should be obvious how to do this.

Comment: I would also utilize the coordinates of a unit square to attempt to minimize/maximize the perimeter of the triangle correct?

Comment: @21shai4: Sorry, I don't understand that at all.

Comment: The coordinates of a unit square are typically A (0,1) B (1,1) C (1,0) and D (0,0) correct? So i'm wondering if that has to do with the solution of this problem as well.

Comment: @21shai4: No. No it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Let the point $P$ partition the side $CD = 1 = a + b$. Then, the perimeter

$$p=1+ AP + BP =1+ \sqrt{1+a^2}+  \sqrt{1+b^2}$$

Use $\frac{db}{da}=-1$ and set,

$$\frac {dp}{da} = \frac{a}{\sqrt{1+a^2}} + \frac{-b} {\sqrt{1+b^2}}=0$$

which yields $a=b =\frac12$ and the minimum perimeter $p=1+\sqrt5$ due to $p’’(\frac12)>0$.

The perimeter $p$ increases when the point P moves away from the midpoint and reaches its maximum  value $p=2+\sqrt2$ where the point P is at the vertexes C or D.